# How to hide a menu from public, but share content with a private link

Tags: menus, conditional-content, private

I would like to create a menu or menu item that can only be seen with a private link.  So the menu would house various pages, but the content can only be seen with a link that is shared. I have searched the plugins and cannot find one to do this.  Most plugins require user logins and it would be my preference not to have users if possible.

Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I personally use [WPFront User Role Editor (free)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpfront-user-role-editor/) on both of my sites, after you set menu buttons only to logged in users to be shown they will disappear from visitors view, there are 4 options to choose from.

1. All Users
2. Logged in Users
3. Guest Users
4. Users by Role

You can give it a try.

*Features*

- Create new roles.
- Edit or rename existing roles.
- Clone existing roles.
- Manage capabilities.
- Allows you to add role capabilities.
- Change default user role.
- Add or Remove capabilities.
- Restore role.
- Assign multiple roles.
- Migrate users.
- **Navigation menu permissions basic.**
- Widget permissions basic.
- Login redirect basic.

Maybe what you ask is achievable but that will require a WP coder to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine two plugins:

1. Any plugin that works for logged in users.
2. A plugin that can generate link for temporary login without registration, like this one https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/temporary-login-without-password/